# class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0/ Cannot access org.testng.annotations.Test

Tags: azure, pipeline, cicd

I used VSCode to write Automation code in JAVA script and pushed the code to Azure Repository.
I have used testNG framework
Now while trying to create a new pipeline on Azure for continous integration of selenium code.
I have selected Maven configuration while creating pipeline
But facing Compilation error as below
** Cannot access org.testng.annotations.Test
bad class  file: C:\\ testng\7.8.0\testng-7.8.0.jar(org/testng/annotations/Test.class)
class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath**

Can anyone please help here?

jdk17 was installed on my machine.  Then I read a answer for similar kind of question on stackoverflow and it said that jdk version of my machine and that of Azure does not match.
Not sure what is the version of jdk on the Azure I am using.
So Then I downgraded jdk on my local machine to jdk11. Still the issue persists.